# How do I get entity framework to let me set a storegeneratedpatternfield?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a field in one of my entities that is being used as a id field. The issue is that this particular field can have duplicates in it due to support versioning data support. I have the field set to populate when it is null using the `storegeneratedpatternfield = identity`. I need to be able to set the field when I am dealing with a new version of the field.

```
//so some basic psuedo code when I update.
entity myentity = //find the entity via linq

myentity.version = //next version number

db.entitytable.add(new entity() { entityid = myentity.entityid, etc.});


savechanges
```

what happens right now is it ignores me setting the field if I use storegeneratedpatternfield = identity or storegeneratedpatternfield = computed

I have a workaround where I look up the new entity but I was wondering if there is another option.